# Simple single page application template bootsrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a bootstrap template that fits entirely on one page with a vertical menu bar being the only scrollable element on the page, issue is the entire page is scrollable.
Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="height:10%;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 bg-success">banner</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="height:80%;">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 bg-success">Menu</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 bg-warning">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="height:10%;">
        <div class="col-lg-12  col-md-12 bg-success">footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try vh instead of %,
style="10vh" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="height:10vh;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 bg-success">banner</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="height:80vh;">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 bg-success">Menu</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 bg-warning">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="height:10vh;">
        <div class="col-lg-12  col-md-12 bg-success">footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this struct, following Bootstrap Documentation.

```css
body, html, main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.h-10v {
  height: 10vh;
}
.h-80v {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body>

  <main>
     <header class="bg-secondary h-10v">
      Banner here.
     </header>
     <section class="row bg-dark h-80v">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg-warning">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 bg-light">
       <p>This area content.</p>
      </div>
     </section>
     <footer class="bg-primary h-10v">
      This is footer.
     </footer>

  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

https://codepen.io/pauloserafimtavares/pen/jpdrBG